# swift | unresolved identifier error

Tags: swift3

Here is the code:

```
let task: URLSessionDataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
     // Get the HTTP status code of the request.
        let statusCode = (response as! HTTPURLResponse).statusCode
        if statusCode == 200 {
            // Convert the received JSON data into a dictionary.
            do {
                if let dataDictionary = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers])) as? [String:Any] { let accessToken = dataDictionary["access_token"] as? String }

                UserDefaults.setObject(accessToken, forKey: "LIAccessToken")
                UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
                    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                    })
            }
            catch {
                print("Could not convert JSON data into a dictionary.")
            }
        }
```

new Code: ( this is from app coda that is not able to compile in latest swift,https://github.com/appcoda/LinkedInSignInDemo/blob/master/LISignIn/WebViewController.swift)

let dataDictionary = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)

```
                let accessToken = dataDictionary["access_token"] as! String

                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(accessToken, forKey: "LIAccessToken")
                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
                })
```

Comment: unresolved identifier accessToken... and when I define it outside, I get more errors

Comment: On which line you are getting that error?

Comment: It's just because the compiler doesn't know what `accesToken` is! See [here](https://learnappmaking.com/unresolved-identifier-understanding-xcode/)

Comment: Learn what [scope](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Programming/Scope) is, it's an essential concept for programmers, you can't do without.

Comment: I am trying to compile the class from appcoda :

Comment: Format and indent your code correctly (unfold the long line) and you will see by yourself why `accessToken` is not accessible from where you try to use it. And if you don't understand that, you need to study what is "scope" as I told you in my previous comment. Read the link (or another similar one). It's important.

Comment: thanks Moritz. I am learning it online and very new to programming. I have updated the original section. The code is from GIT app coda

Comment: You're welcome, and really, I insist, this concept of "scope" is very important, learn it the way you want but learn it. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use like this :

You defined `accessToken` in if loop. And you are accessing it outside of it.

```
if let dataDictionary = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers])) as? [String:Any] { 
    let accessToken = dataDictionary["access_token"] as? String 
    UserDefaults.setObject(accessToken, forKey: "LIAccessToken")
}
```

Comment: This brings other error : instance member 'setObject' cannot be used on type 'UserDefaults'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead? ---- How to get rid of it?